# Using Infinispan's EmbeddedCacheManager with Openshift

Tags: java, jboss7.x, openshift, infinispan

I am trying to use Infinispan as a cache for my Java application hosted with JBoss AS 7 on Openshift.

I have the following cluster configuration in `standalone.xml`.

```
<cache-container name="cluster" aliases="ha-partition" default-cache="default">
    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
    <replicated-cache name="default" mode="SYNC" batching="true" start="EAGER">
        <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
    </replicated-cache>
</cache-container>
```

I tried accessing the cache with the following code snippet.

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/cluster")
EmbeddedCacheManager container;

private Cache<String, Integer> foo = container.getCache("foo", true);
```

However, a `NullPointerException` is thrown on the line where with `container.getCache`. This is presumably because the `lookup` failed to find a value for `container`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Here's a blog](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/infinispan-polyglot-persistence-part-4) related to your question which contains an example.  Can you review it to see if it helps?

Comment: @NamDuong I was actually following that blog post. The primary examples they gave was with Spring though. I need an example that uses `@Resource(lookup =)`

Comment: Hmmm strange, we have a [quickstart](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/jboss-as7) precisely for this and I can't see any real differences. Maybe you wanna try to run that quickstart locally in your own machine taking the latest AS7 version? If that doesn't work, try using JBoss EAP 6.1.0 from [here](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas).

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the `getCache` call in your `@postconstuct` method